# Scrapy Pausing and resuming crawls, results directory

Tags: scrapy, output, resume

I have finished a scraping project using resume mode. but I don't know where the results are.

scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1

I look at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html, but it does not indicate anything about it

¿Where is the file with the results?

```
2020-09-10 23:31:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-10 23:31:31 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'bans/error/scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11.TunnelError': 22,
 'bans/error/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 2,
 'bans/error/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 6891,
 'bans/error/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 8424,
 'bans/status/500': 9598,
 'bans/status/503': 56,
 'downloader/exception_count': 15339,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11.TunnelError': 22,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 2,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 6891,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 8424,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 9530,
 'downloader/request_count': 172,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 172,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1848,
 'downloader/response_count': 170,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 169,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 9,
 'downloader/response_status_count/503': 56,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1717,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 2, 31, 31, 32),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 67,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/500': 67,
 'item_scraped_count': 120,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 357,
 'log_count/ERROR': 119,
 'log_count/INFO': 1764,
 'log_count/WARNING': 240,
 'proxies/dead': 1,
 'proxies/good': 1,
 'proxies/mean_backoff': 0.0,
 'proxies/reanimated': 0,
 'proxies/unchecked': 0,
 'response_received_count': 169,
 'retry/count': 1019,
 'retry/max_reached': 93,
 'retry/reason_count/500 Internal Server Error': 867,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 80,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 72,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1722,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 1722,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1722,
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 1722,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 9, 2, 48, 56, 908)}
2020-09-10 23:31:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

(Face python 3.8) D:\Selenium\Face python 3.8\TORBUSCADORDELINKS\TORBUSCADORDELINKS\spiders>
 'retry/reason_count/500 Internal Server Error': 867,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 80,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 72,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1722673,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 1722,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1722,
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 1722,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 9, 2, 48, 56, 908)}
2020-09-10 23:31:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command,

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

does not indicate an output file path.

Because of that, your results are nowhere.

Use the `-o` command-line switch to specify an output path.

See also [the Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), which covers this. Or run `scrapy crawl --help`.